# Typescript inference error when returning generics

Tags: typescript, generics, inference

Im having a hard time trying to wrap my head around this.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCuEAuB7AtgUQE5ZVgPBgHwDeAUNNAA7wBGIAlsNGgKZRgDmrA-AFzRkWBgDtOAbgrU6jZsBQATVgIySyU%20SKHxgqLAAp5SlQBoW7CF14ChozgEpylSkgAWDCADo2HbtAC85r6sks7Qbh6eRqwB0NGh0AC%20ZMnqoJAwACrsSNDkFAD0BdCZAMrQogBmrMJi0FisSPBYItCQcIiomDh4%20CSJRNAAPh3I6Ni4BCLwICBEhcUA6q4AnhUwDJwieHaUCGPdk-i0KCggrGAig5cKo10TvbZig9BSNPRM0KwAHqzA8EhWPpHOowgxKvoIl4sDd0AB5Kg1MBIBgoETAgKBSpgEAQVggsJhBpNFrQESsADud3GPQMAHJssg6fYEpRUmCIVDPDCRAp4YiYSi0Rj-FicXiCYTKMTmq1yVT9vdafoAEwsqRs0HOcGQ9zQ2FoBFIoXo%20yY6DY3H4pxS%20qNWVkynUw54fT9dVhdnOGWk%20XOh4GaazD1JdRvGSfHl8w0C5Go0027320kAWWRrm5BoxgwADJ4AKwJVKJIA)

Why does Typescypt infer only some of the return types (check the playground)? what Im doing wrong?

For what I saw, this only happens when using generics.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include the relevant code _in the question itself_. See [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not ignoring them, it's just that `CustomError<{}>` is enough to cover the string and the number. Both `string` and `2` are assignable to type `{}`.

```
// No errors with either of these
const test: {} = 'Test';
const test2: {} = 2;
```

So typescript could either say the return type is `CustomError<{}> | CustomError<null>`, or that it's `CustomError<{}> | CustomError<string> | CustomError<number> | CustomError<null>`, but since there's no difference between the two, typescript used the shorter one.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/PTAEDkHtQUwJzpOBnUB3AlgFwBa2zvKJAGai4zIwBQAxpAHbJbmVYBcoA3gL6gC8oAOQAVNkIDcdRs1bMATJ14DQ8iUA)

If you change the case with an object to a more complex object, such that string and number no longer match with it, then you'll see the number and string appear in the return type:

```
if(this.randomOperation() == false){
  return new CustomError({ hello: 'world });
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCuEAuB7AtgUQE5ZVgPBgHwDeAUNNAA7wBGIAlsNGgKZRgDmrA-AFzRkWBgDtOAbgrU6jZsBQATVgIySyU%20SKHxgqLAAp5SlQBoW7CF14ChozgEpylSkgAWDCADo2HbtAC85r6sks7Qbh6eRqwB0NGh0AC%20ZMnqoJAwACrsSNDkUjT0TNCsAB6swPBIrPqO6mEMAGb6EV5YYCIK6ADyVKztSAwoIrUBgY1gIBCsdWFhWKxI8Fgi0CKsAO5wiKiYOHj6AOTZyIf2CZSpDc2tnu2dPX0DQyP2Y9ATUzNOc5QLSys1pttsh0NhcAYAEznKSXerOJotdxtDpdNC9fpgQbDUb%20caTaazX7Qf7LVbrLYIUF7CH6EjQVysEAgFACQ4bPAgBSHJIwsJXZykwEUkG7cEHETwZl8pLqAoyYr3NEY544omCxZk6AAWSxrjuqPQoyI0AADJ4AKwJVKJIA)